# How to insert a newly generated id into another table with a trigger in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically, users when they create a new record in mytable1, there is an id field that needs to be the same across multiple tables. I achieve this by having mytable2 with the s_id as primary key

My current function looks like

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.new_record()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $function$

 BEGIN
case when new.s_id in (select s_id from mytable1) then
insert into mytable2 (sprn, date_created) select max(s_id) +1, now() from mytable2 ;
update mytable1 set new.s_id = (select max(b.s_id) from mytable2 b);
end case;

RETURN new;
END;

$function$;
```

Intended was when the s_id is replicated then it would create a new entry on mytable2. This new entry would then be updated onto mytable1

Problem with this function is that right now it does not recognise the new on the update part of the function.

How to keep the s_id take the value on every new insert ?

Comment: Using `max()` to "generate" ids is a terrible idea. Why don't you simply use the same sequence for both tables?

Comment: Is that trigger function for table1 or table2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name whenever I tried, a sequence could only be owned by a single table. the trigger is for whenever table1 gets an insert

Comment: A sequence can indeed only be *owned*  by one column. But it can be _used_ anywhere. And you don't have have to make it be owned by a column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but the problem here is that the column needs to be the unique reference between multiple tables. If I use a sequence, would it also insert onto the table2? I'm kinda confused

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have one "generator" across multiple tables, create one sequence that is used across all those tables for the default value:

```
create sequence the_id_sequence;

create table one 
(
  id integer primary key default nextval('the_id_sequence')
  .... other columns
);


create table two
(
  id integer primary key default nextval('the_id_sequence')
  .... other columns ...
);
```

---

If you want to *replicate* an ID from one table to another during insert, you only need one sequence:

```
create table one 
(
  -- using identity is the preferred over "serial" to auto-generate PK values
  id integer primary key generated always as identity
);

create table two
(
  id integer primary key
);

create or replace function insert_two()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  insert into two (id) values (new.id);
  return new;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;

create trigger replicate_id
  before insert on one
  for each row 
  execute procedure insert_two();
```

Then if you run:

```sql
insert into one (id) values (default);
```

A row with exactly the same id value will be inserted into table two.

---

If you don't have a generated ID column so far, use the following syntax:

```
alter table one 
   add testidcolumn bigint generated always as identity;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So for me to understand, if I set the default on all the tables to the value on this sequence, when I then set up my trigger it will insert the same id onto all the tables?

Comment: @Luffydude: I don't understand what the trigger is for. If you want a unique ID across multiple tables, then no trigger is needed. Your trigger only seems to be a very bad implementation of a sequence.

Comment: Ermm. From what I understand, a sequence gives unique ids. But on this case I would need the same id being replicated across the tables whenever someone does an insert. Say user1 creates row 100 on table1 and the sequence gives it an id of 50. User2 will then need to see the id50 but on table2.

Comment: @Luffydude: this sounds like a really strange requirement, but see my edit. Why do you have two different tables if there is a one-to-one mapping between them? A single table might be a better solution.

Comment: I just read that you can't just add identity to an existing table :(

Comment: @Luffydude: do you already have a `serial` column? That's essentially the same.

Comment: Unfortunately no because it's not the primary key for table1. Usually people copy pasta stuff from a different table onto table1. I read that doing generated by default instead of generated always provides what i need and doesnt just create mass new random ids. Problem is I cant seem to find the right syntax and documentation isnt clear. If I do alter table table1 add testidcolumn bigint generated by DEFAULT AS identity ( nextval'sequence' ) it doesn't work

Comment: @Luffydude: you don't need to specify a default clause when adding an identity column. See my edit

Comment: Alright so I created a new column and set up the trigger as you have in the answer. Problem was when I did an insert with a null value, it returned: SQL Error [23502]: ERROR: null value in column "" violates not-null constraint. Either it's trying to do an insert calling the new.id with a null value or it's just not giving it a new value with the identity thing